# EditText to have only numbers and hide input value

Tags: android, android-edittext, addtextchangedlistener

What I want is the `EditText` to accept only one input value which is a number and to have password attribute. I also want, if I enter value, say in first `EditText`, I should focus to next `EditText`. Similarly, if I press delete button of softkeyboard, its focus should go backwards like say, from `EditText`2 to `EditText` 1. Mix all these and password attribute doesn't work properly.
And don't downvote without actually trying out the code.

This is the layout I have right now.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pinc_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.16"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textColor="@color/border_color" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pinc_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.16"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textColor="@color/border_color" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pinc_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.16"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textColor="@color/border_color" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pinc_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.16"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textColor="@color/border_color" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pinc_5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.16"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textColor="@color/border_color" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pinc_6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.16"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textColor="@color/border_color" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Java Code ::

```
pinc_1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pinc_1.length() == 1) {
                pinc_1.clearFocus();
                pinc_2.requestFocus();
                pinc_2.setCursorVisible(true);
            } else {

            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    pinc_2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pinc_2.length() == 1) {

                pinc_2.clearFocus();
                pinc_3.requestFocus();
                pinc_3.setCursorVisible(true);
            } else {

                pinc_2.clearFocus();
                pinc_1.requestFocus();
                pinc_1.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    pinc_3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pinc_3.length() == 1) {

                pinc_3.clearFocus();
                pinc_4.requestFocus();
                pinc_4.setCursorVisible(true);
            } else {

                pinc_3.clearFocus();
                pinc_2.requestFocus();
                pinc_2.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    pinc_4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pinc_4.length() == 1) {

                pinc_4.clearFocus();
                pinc_5.requestFocus();
                pinc_5.setCursorVisible(true);
            } else {

                pinc_4.clearFocus();
                pinc_3.requestFocus();
                pinc_3.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    pinc_5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pinc_5.length() == 1) {

                pinc_5.clearFocus();
                pinc_6.requestFocus();
                pinc_6.setCursorVisible(true);
            } else {

                pinc_5.clearFocus();
                pinc_4.requestFocus();
                pinc_4.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {


        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    pinc_6.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pinc_6.length() == 1) {

                pinc_6.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager inputManager =
                        (InputMethodManager) getActivity().
                                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                        getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            } else {

                pinc_6.clearFocus();
                pinc_5.requestFocus();
                pinc_5.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

I have also tried this way::

```
    pinc_2.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{back_filter_pin2, new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1)});
InputFilter back_filter_pin2 = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            if (end == 0) {
                pinc_1.requestFocus();
            } else if (end == 1) {
                pinc_2.clearFocus();
                pinc_3.requestFocus();

            }

            return source;
        }
    };
```

Also have tried:

```
  pinc_6.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER |
  InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: not able to mask the input value to "*" which password attribute does.

Comment: Is it working before you write the ontextchange method in activity

Comment: @SibinDavis yes, addTextChangedListener screws things up.

Comment: It will wok if yo change your logic to '  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }' from  'onTextChanged' method.I have tested it. Its working fine.

Comment: lol. it's working now. thanks all.

Comment: Then Please accept an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all use your condition inside

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
```

To focus your cursor to previous field when delete text you can check length with 0 like this ...

```
 if (pinc_2.length() == 1) {
    pinc_2.clearFocus();
    pinc_3.requestFocus();
    pinc_3.setCursorVisible(true);
 } else if (pinc_2.length() == 0) {
    pinc_2.clearFocus();
    pinc_1.requestFocus();
    pinc_1.setCursorVisible(true);
 }
```

I tested it ... it will work... Enjoy coding :)

### Edit

Complete code for all EditText

### I little bet add something for 6th EditText see that..

```
pinc_1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() == 1) {
                pinc_1.clearFocus();
                pinc_2.requestFocus();
                pinc_2.setCursorVisible(true);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });

    pinc_2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if (s.length() == 1) {
                pinc_2.clearFocus();
                pinc_3.requestFocus();
                pinc_3.setCursorVisible(true);
            } else if (s.length() == 0) {
                pinc_2.clearFocus();
                pinc_1.requestFocus();
                pinc_1.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });

    pinc_3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if (s.length() == 1) {
                pinc_3.clearFocus();
                pinc_4.requestFocus();
                pinc_4.setCursorVisible(true);
            } else if (s.length() == 0) {
                pinc_3.clearFocus();
                pinc_2.requestFocus();
                pinc_2.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });

    pinc_4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if (s.length() == 1) {
                pinc_4.clearFocus();
                pinc_5.requestFocus();
                pinc_5.setCursorVisible(true);
            } else if (s.length() == 0) {
                pinc_4.clearFocus();
                pinc_3.requestFocus();
                pinc_3.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });

    pinc_5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if (s.length() == 1) {
                pinc_5.clearFocus();
                pinc_6.requestFocus();
                pinc_6.setCursorVisible(true);
            } else if (s.length() == 0) {
                pinc_5.clearFocus();
                pinc_4.requestFocus();
                pinc_4.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });


    pinc_6.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        CharSequence privText = "";

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
            privText = s;
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if (s.length() > 1) {
                pinc_6.setText(privText);
            } else if (s.length() == 0) {
                pinc_6.clearFocus();
                pinc_5.requestFocus();
                pinc_5.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First make the editText xml input type to number password only.

> android:inputType="numericPassword"

and the size of it

> android:maxLength="1"

For the editText then..

```
editText1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(editText1.getText().length() == 1)
            editText2.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Your code as

```
pinc_1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pinc_1.length() == 1) {
                pinc_1.clearFocus();
                pinc_2.requestFocus();
                pinc_2.setCursorVisible(true);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });

    pinc_2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pinc_2.length() == 1) {

                pinc_2.clearFocus();
                pinc_3.requestFocus();
                pinc_3.setCursorVisible(true);
            } else {

                pinc_2.clearFocus();
                pinc_1.requestFocus();
                pinc_1.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });

    pinc_3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pinc_3.length() == 1) {

                pinc_3.clearFocus();
                pinc_4.requestFocus();
                pinc_4.setCursorVisible(true);
            } else {

                pinc_3.clearFocus();
                pinc_2.requestFocus();
                pinc_2.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });

    pinc_4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pinc_4.length() == 1) {

                pinc_4.clearFocus();
                pinc_5.requestFocus();
                pinc_5.setCursorVisible(true);
            } else {

                pinc_4.clearFocus();
                pinc_3.requestFocus();
                pinc_3.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });

    pinc_5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {


        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pinc_5.length() == 1) {

                pinc_5.clearFocus();
                pinc_6.requestFocus();
                pinc_6.setCursorVisible(true);
            } else {

                pinc_5.clearFocus();
                pinc_4.requestFocus();
                pinc_4.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });

    pinc_6.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pinc_6.length() == 1) {

                pinc_6.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager inputManager =
                        (InputMethodManager) getActivity().
                                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                        getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            } else {

                pinc_6.clearFocus();
                pinc_5.requestFocus();
                pinc_5.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

It is working fine. I have tested it.